# Объединение нескольких дисков в одну fs

Tags: windows, ntfs

Есть четыре жёстких диск. Нужно объединить все 4 диска, чтобы Windows работала со всеми дисками как с диском C: (Важно чтобы не было ограничения на размер какую-либо директорию, так что нельзя просто смонтировать диск в директорию). Это возможно? Если да, то как?

Comment: RAID-массив? . .

Comment: [дисковые пространства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/overview)?